# Can I test whether an auto-reset event is signaled with this strategy?

Tags: windows, winapi, synchronization

I'd like to emit debug output that contains the state of an auto-reset event. This is to aid concurrency debugging.

It's possible to test the current state of an auto-reset event by waiting on it with a timeout of zero. Unfortunately, this resets the event. So I thought, I'd first test it and the just set it again if it was set already.

Would this strategy work in the sense that it can't possibly alter the behavior of the rest of the application?

Comment: you need call `ZwQueryEvent` with `EventBasicInformation` - and you got `EVENT_BASIC_INFORMATION` which containing `EventState`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would this strategy work in the sense that it can't possibly alter the
> behavior of the rest of the application?

of course this can affect behavior of the rest of the application. because you not only query state, but change state of event with this.

however special api exist (undocumented) for query information of event - it type and state (of course state after api return can change at any type)

```
typedef struct EVENT_BASIC_INFORMATION
{
    EVENT_TYPE EventType;
    LONG EventState;
} *PEVENT_BASIC_INFORMATION;

enum EVENT_INFORMATION_CLASS
{
    EventBasicInformation
};

EXTERN_C
NTSYSAPI
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
NtQueryEvent (
               _In_ HANDLE EventHandle,
               _In_ EVENT_INFORMATION_CLASS EventInformationClass,
               _Out_writes_bytes_(Length) PVOID EventInformation,
               _In_ ULONG Length,
               _Out_opt_ PULONG ReturnLength
               );
```

example of usage

```
if (HANDLE hEvent = CreateEventW(0, 0, 0, 0))
{
    EVENT_BASIC_INFORMATION ebi;
    NtQueryEvent(hEvent, EventBasicInformation, &ebi, sizeof(ebi), 0);
    SetEvent(hEvent);
    NtQueryEvent(hEvent, EventBasicInformation, &ebi, sizeof(ebi), 0);
    NtClose(hEvent);
}
```

note, that *auto-reset* event - this is *SynchronizationEvent* and *manual-reset* event - this is *NotificationEvent*

Comment: Thanks! Didn't find this technique in my research. Others claimed it was impossible.

Comment: The question has the [tag:winapi] tag, and to my knowledge there is no solution to the stated problem in the Windows API. This proposed answer doesn't use the Windows API. It is based on the [Native API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_API) instead. Given the restrictions implied by the question the claim that this were impossible may well be true.

Comment: @IInspectable *api* is only exported function from some dll. for instance `CreateEventW` is exported function from *kernel32.dll*, *NtQueryEvent* and *ZwQueryEvent* exported functions from *ntdll.dll* - no any different in how this api used in called.

Comment: The difference is that the Windows API is the supported programming interface, and the Native API is an unsupported programming interface. An API is far more than a set of exported functions: There is documentation, a software development kit, and contractual guarantees.

Comment: @IInspectable - *Native API is an unsupported programming interface.* - very debatable. also exist and another solution. even more simply but double undocumented - use [`QueryMemoryResourceNotification`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-querymemoryresourcenotification) here. `BOOL EventState;
  QueryMemoryResourceNotification(hEvent, &EventState);` - this already win32 api in all senses, but not documented usage of api

Comment: @IInspectable you could be right in your interpretation of the tag name. I'll still let the tag stand because I think it helps the question to be discovered by interested people.

Comment: @boo That was commenting on the claim, that this were not possible using the Windows API. It seems, that claim holds true. It wasn't meant to have you change the tags on your question. There is a distinct difference between an official, documented API, and one that isn't. That difference does not appear to be a meaningful one to the author here, leading them to believe that there were no difference at all. This is wrong. The difference unarguably exists, and it *is* a meaningful one to others. If anything needs change then this proposed answer should be more explicit on this.

Comment: @IInspectable many ntapi official documented too. also some api declared in wdm.h, ntdddh.k, ntifs.h but not formal documented. also *that this were not possible using the Windows API. It seems, that claim holds true.* - are `QueryMemoryResourceNotification` is win32 api ? this api call exactly do task here, despite not documented to such usage

Comment: You cannot use `QueryMemoryResourceNotification` with a handle other than *"a handle to a memory resource notification object"*. The fact that it may appear to work with an event handle (today) is purely coincidential, not contractual. Like any other API call, using it out-of-spec is not supported. Again, if this is not something that's meaningful to you doesn't mean that it weren't meaningful to others.

Comment: @IInspectable - a handle to a memory resource notification object - this is handle to event - `\KernelObjects\LowMemoryCondition` or `\KernelObjects\HighMemoryCondition` and `QueryMemoryResourceNotification` internal call `ZwQueryEvent`. this realeted to your comment - *not possible using the Windows API* - possible even if use your sense of win32 api set, but not documented. not documented != not possible. anyway i also prefer not use internal implementation of `QueryMemoryResourceNotification` but direct call to `ZwQueryEvent`